# onMove and onStart html event in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[In this line](https://github.com/react-component/slider/blob/master/src/Range.jsx#L75) where does the onStart function come from? I did not see this component used dragging plugin. The author did not used it in the render function too, wonder it does.

Comment: It's not being called anywhere. It must be there to allow other components to call it by using Refs.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson I thought ref can only be use to retrieve DOM node? ref can call function too?

Comment: Refs on native html elements such as `<div />` will give a DOM node. Refs on custom React components will give you the instance.